# using radio buttons in a html table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, radio-button

Rather noobish question but I have tried searching and just cannot find a solution. My problem is I have a table called Off, which stores all of the staffs holidays. However before a staff member may have that day off it has to be authorised. I have a query which gets all of the unauthorised holidays and I display them in a html table. The problem is that I need 2 radio buttons per record. one for authorise and one for deny. The radio buttons are displayed but when going through the records only one of the radio buttons is selectable. Is it possible to use radio buttons in this way?

```
<?php 
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/Apollo/dbc.php";
include_once($path);



$rs_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM off WHERE IsItAuthorised='0' and isitsick='0' ORDER BY DayOff");

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Administration Main Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<?php


    $limit = count($OffID);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //Assign each array to a variable
    $id = $_POST['OffID'];
    $answer = $_POST['radio'];



    $limit = count($OffID);




$values = array(); // initialize an empty array to hold the values
    for($k=0;$k<$limit;$k++){
    $msg[] = "$limit New KPI's Added";


          $query = "UPDATE Off SET IsItAuthorised = '{$answer[$k]}' WHERE OffID = '{$OffID[$k]}'";
    }



    $Event = "INSERT INTO events (UserName, Event ) VALUES ('$_SESSION[user_name]', 'Entered New KPI' )";   



if (!mysql_query($query,$link)){
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    } else {

        mysql_query($Event);
        echo "<div class=\"msg\">" . $msg[0] . "</div>";
    }




}                             
?>


</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="14%" valign="top"><?php

?>

    </td>
    <td width="74%" valign="top" style="padding: 10px;">

      <p><?php 
      if(!empty($msg)) {
      echo $msg[0];
      }
      ?></p>

      <p>
        <?php 
      $cond = '';






      $sql = "select * from off ";



      $rs_total = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
      $total = mysql_num_rows($rs_total);


      ?>

      <p>

        <form name "searchform" action="/Apollo/Admin/HolidayRequests" method="post">
        <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
          <tr class="mytables"> 
            <td width="4%"><font color="white"><strong>ID</font></strong></td>
            <td width="4%"> <font color="white"><strong>Staff Member</font></strong></td>
            <td width="10%"><font color="white"><strong>Day Off</font></strong></div></td>
             <td width="10%"><font color="white"><strong>Is It Authorized</font></strong></div></td>
            <td width="15%">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>


          <tr> 
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="17%"><div align="center"></div></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <?php while ($rrows = mysql_fetch_array($rs_results)) {?>
          <tr> 
            <td><input type="" name="id[]" id="id[]" size="4" value="<?php echo $rrows['OffID'];?>" /></td>
            <td><?php echo $rrows['StaffMember']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($rrows['DayOff']));?></div></td>

            <td> <span id="approve<?php echo $rrows['id']; ?>"> 
              <?php if(!$rrows['IsItAuthorised']) { echo "Pending"; } else {echo "Authorized"; }?>
              </span> </td>

              <td>


                    <input type="radio" name="radio[0]"  id="radio[0]" value="1" />Approve
                        <input type="radio" name="radio[1]"  id="radio[1]"  value="0" />Deny



         </td>
          </tr>

          <?php } ?>
        </table>
          <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>


      &nbsp;</p>
      <?php


      ?>


      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    <td width="12%">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you mean you can only select one radio button at a time per row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is to do with your use of the "name" attribute - this attribute is used in a special way on radio buttons.

When you click on a radio button, all the other radio buttons with the same name are deselected - in your case, you will have half of the radio buttons on the page in one group and half in another, which would probably explain why you can only select one. I'd imagine you can actually select two at the same time, if you click on the right radio buttons.

To fix this you'd need to have some kind of count for the while loop, ie:

```
$resultNumber = 0;
while ($rrows = mysql_fetch_array($rs_results)) {
```

Then you'd need to use this number in the name (and also id) of the radio buttons -

```
<input type="radio" name="radio<?php echo $resultNumber; ?>"  id="radio<?php echo $resultNumber; ?>" value="1" />
```

Then simply increment the `$resultNumber` at the end of each iteration -

```
<?php 
    $resultNumber++;
} 
?>
```

Alternatively, you could use the primary key of the row from the database table you're querying to distinguish groups, but not knowing the table structure I couldn't give sample code for that.

Further reading on radio buttons (also a source for the name attribute problem) :
http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm

Answer (score 0):

Instead of radio buttons, I used checkboxes, which I looped through. Each checkbox set a value to a different column. Should have been obvious to me to begin with.